Error After Suspend - Nvidia Graphics Card Fails
I've been having this issue for a while now, and it's starting to really annoy me as I use it.
After I press suspend, I get an error after resuming and have to turn my computer off and on again manually, losing all my previous work. This only happens if I press "Suspend."

Here is my journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day' after rebooting.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHC error in resume, USBSTS 0x401, Reinit
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: ata5: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: usb 3-2: PM: dpm_run_callback(): usb_dev_resume+0x0/0x20 returns -5
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: usb 3-2: PM: failed to resume async: error -5
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd-sleep[22860]: System returned from sleep state.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd[1]: Finished System Suspend.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop systemd-logind[937]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop ModemManager[993]: <info> [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is resuming
Jun 22 19:26:08 desktop NetworkManager[909]: <info> [1719102368.5200] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes enabled: yes)
-- Boot aa259e80413346049690b821d7030951 --
Jun 22 19:27:43 desktop kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic root=UUID=aff2a414-6e81-474d-9adb-952ea64156d5 ro nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1 vt.handoff=7
Jun 22 19:27:43 desktop kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic root=UUID=aff2a414-6e81-474d-9adb-952ea64156d5 ro nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1 vt.handoff=7
Jun 22 19:27:43 desktop kernel: ata5: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
Jun 22 19:27:47 desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3363]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-41-generic root=UUID=aff2a414-6e81-474d-9adb-952ea64156d5 ro nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1 vt.handoff=7

If I do not manually press suspend and let it suspend itself, the computer does start and can resume. However, my Nvidia graphics card fails in Python (although nvidia-smi and nvcc -V work fine) and I have to reboot it to get the graphics card working again.

  Version: Ubuntu 22.04
  AMD Ryzen 9 5900X
  NZXT N7 B550 motherboard
  EVGA GeForce RTX 3090
I am dual booting with Windows on another SSD, and Windows does not have this problem.
